# When should i unregister system events to prevent memoryleaks?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, systemevent

I am using systemevents like this:

```
            SystemEvents.SessionEnding += SystemEventsSessionEnding;
```

to detect when user shutsdown or log off, but i have read that i need to unregister this event to prevent memoryleaks and such.

When/Where should i do that?

I have seen that i can do that in SystemEvents.EventsThreadShutdown, this event will fire BEFORE the system events fires, and IF this is true, then this should be the place where i should unregister my systemevents?

Or should i do that in my mainforms FormClosing event? Will the FormClosing event get fired att all times?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to be alerted when that event is fired throughout the lifetime of your application instance then no, you don't need to unregister it.  If you have objects that go out of scope which subscribe to that event then they should unregister as the event object holds a reference to the subscriber, preventing it from being GC'd.

Comment: S, I only need to be alerted when my application gets termninated so i can save some data and unregister systemevent ( which i probably dont need after reading 2 answers ).

Comment: According to the docs `Caution Because this is a static event, you must detach your event handlers when your application is disposed, or memory leaks will result.` - see more in [my comments to Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292013/when-should-i-unregister-system-events-to-prevent-memoryleaks#comment120536866_7292019).

Answer (score 3):

Are you only subscribing once, at the start of your program, and you would only unsubscribe when your process is terminating? If so, don't bother.

When your process has terminated, if there are any "system level" hooks around it's the operating system's duty to clean those up for you - you don't need to worry about it. It's not like the operating system is going to prevent your objects from being garbage collected despite the process not existing any more :)

Comment: @jon skeet , i am only subscribing once at start of the program and yes, i thought i needed to unsubscribe at the termination of my application. But maybe i dont even need to as you say? I am saving some data so the data dont get lost in the systemending event , but thats all.

Comment: @syncis: Then no, you don't need to unsubscribe.

Comment: Your answer (and comments) that there is no need to unsubscribe to `SystemEvents` seems to contradict the docs which say `Caution Because this is a static event, you must detach your event handlers when your application is disposed, or memory leaks will result.` e.g. [TimeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged#remarks), [SessionSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch#remarks), etc. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @ispiro: It sounds like you may not have taken the first paragraph into account. (A process that has been terminated can't leak memory.)

Comment: So why do the docs say to unsubscribe `when your application is disposed`? Obviously a disposed application won't leak. I'm therefore assuming that the `or memory leaks will result.` in the docs do _not_ refer to my application, rather, that there will be a memory leak _in Windows_ which will keep the "subscription" and try to notify the nonexistent application thereby creating a memory leak in Windows (the OS). How else can we understand the docs I linked to above?

Comment: @ispiro: I honestly don't know - it seems very odd to me. But if a terminated process causes a memory leak in Windows, that sounds like an OS bug...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks.